# Migrating mounts with identical permissions not working

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, mount, rsync, ntfs-3g

I have two mounts `/mount1` and `/mount2`. I ran the command:

```
rsync -azrt /mount1/* /mount2/
```

to clone everything from `/mount1` to `/mount2`.

I then altered the `/etc/fstab` *(see below)* to remove `/mount1` and mount `/mount2` to `/mount1` but things (including my email servers local user folders) are not working properly for permission reasons anymore, even though when comparing the permissions with the mounts before and after they are identical?!

---

#### `/etc/fstab` before (working):

```
UUID="3999A4F22570EAC4" /mount2   ntfs-3g nobootwait,permissions,locale=en_US.utf8    0   2
mhddfs#/mount3,/mount4 /mount1 fuse defaults,allow_other,nobootwait,nonempty,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=007 0 0
```

#### `/etc/fstab` after (not working):

```
UUID="3999A4F22570EAC4" /mount1   ntfs-3g nobootwait,permissions,locale=en_US.utf8    0   2
```

<sub>Where `UUID="3999A4F22570EAC4"` is `/mount2` that has the content of the previous `/mount1`</sub>

Comment: `uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=007` permissions suggest that only your user (I assume your id is 1000) had access in the first place.  Apart from root, who generally gets to override everything (although not the lack of `allow_other`) .  Hypothetically you could have used ACLs to grant access to other users, but then I notice you didn't specify `-A` to rsync to copy ACLs. Can you confirm that this is what you expect, and whether the problem is for your user, root, or both?  Also whether you deliberately used ACLs.

Comment: I did not deliberately use ACLs as I have no idea what they are. I basically have a symbolic link at `/var/mail/vhosts/` to the `mhddfs` mount that works fine but I now want to get rid of mhddfs as it is a massive bottleneck and have it directly to the mount. But when I do the above I get permission errors in my logs :(

Comment: So it's not root trying to access it, I guess. `ls -l /var/mail/vhosts/` shows all files as owned by your user and group, permissions `rw-`...`---`, right?

Comment: `drwxrwx--- 1 user user`

Comment: Very confused as to why this does not work.

Comment: Yeah :). 1) It would be nice if you had shown a few errors from your log, i.e. showing the filename & program. 2) The files in the top-level `/var/mail/` are typically owned by group `mail` in order to allow the mail delivery agent to write to them. So I'm curious what software you run to write to your `mail/vhosts` directory, and what user+group it is running under?

Comment: 3) Are all the underlying filesystems ntfs-3g?

Comment: 1. `Error: chdir(/var/mail/vhosts/user/julie/) failed: Permission denied`. 2.`/var/mail/` is owned by user `vhosts` but all the files in the `mail/vhosts` directory are owned by `user`. 3. yes

Comment: It might probably also have helped to show the full fstab entries for mount3 and mount4.  ntfs-3g permissions seem to be quite complex. Anway I'm looking at the description of the FUSE option `default_permissions`; it raises the possibility that the `mhddfs` mount actually allowed read-write access by all users, regardless of apparent file permissions.  Can you check that, e.g. set up <del>a file</del> a directory where the permissions only allow root to write to it, and then try writing to it from your normal user?

Comment: I can't change the permission of the file!! So strange!!

Comment: Gah. I guess `uid=1000` will prevent `chown`. Does chmod work? Then you can test `mkdir t; chmod a-w t; touch t/f`. On a standard posix filesystem it will fail, but if the FUSE mount doesn't do permissions checking then it should succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Generic FUSE options

1) I noticed `allow_other` wasn't set on the `ntfs-3g` filesystem mount.  The default for FUSE is not to allow access by other users.  `mhddfs` is a FUSE filesystem and so is `ntfs-3g` (but see next section).

2) When you use `allow_other`, you also want to consider permissions checking.  The default for FUSE is not to check permissions.  So just adding `allow_other` to a filesystem can make it accessible by all users.  This is probably undesirable; separate user IDs are often used to contain services, like the CUPS printer daemon, in case they are compromised by network attack.  To enable user/group/mode permissions checks on generic FUSE filesystems, the option is called `default_permissions`.

### NTFS-3G specific behaviour

1 -> According to its `man` page, `ntfs-3g` will enable `allow_other` by default.  (FUSE defaults will only allow the root user to do that.  Not a problem here though, as you're using `mount` which runs as root).

2 -> It sounds like the `ntfs-3g` option `permissions` enabled permission checking for you.  Otherwise, you wouldn't have noticed any permission errors.  (SELinux might do, but you're not using SELinux, because you're on Ubuntu.  Ubuntu AppArmor is described as being path-based, so from what you've described I think it's unlikely to be causing a problem).

### Thesis

I believe your ntfs-3g mount is set up to perform permission checks, and FUSE is not separately blocking access by other users.  This sounds sensible for a mount in `fstab` which is used to provide system directories like `/var/mail`.

**However your `mhddfs` mount is not performing permission checks itself, because it does not have `default_permissions` set.  That would explain why the `mhddfs` setup was able to work** (despite options for `uid,gid,umask` which only allow access to your user-id 1000).  You don't show the underlying filesystems, so I don't know whether they're checking permissions, but I suspect that `mhddfs` is simply running as root and avoiding the permissions checks that way.

Here's a test you could run on the `mhddfs` mount.  It should show if the permission bits are being checked or not.

```
mkdir dir
chmod a-w dir  # make directory read-only
touch dir/t    # attempt writing to directory
```

**To solve your permission errors, you need to determine which user(s) should have what access to the files in question, and set the correct permissions accordingly.**  You've never said what user (or even what software) is failing the permission checks so it's hard to be any more specific.

Comment: That did not work unfortunately :(

Comment: note - above comment was in response to "you need to set `allow_other`". possibly i should have created a separate answer instead of fixing this one.